# Is it possible to keep a handle of a ::ReplaceFile?

Tags: c++, winapi

I would like to call [::ReplaceFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-replacefilea) while still having a [lock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-lockfileex) of the replaced file for my process so that no other process is reading the file while the replacement takes place. Having a lock requires that the file is [opened](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea) and stays open as long as the lock should exist.

> If a process [...] closes a file that has outstanding locks, the locks are unlocked by the operating system.

[See here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-lockfileex)

Unfortunately, `::ReplaceFile` fails as long as I have an open handle:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Windows.h"

int main() {
    HANDLE fileHandle = ::CreateFile(
        L"Hello.txt",
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
        FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
        NULL,
        OPEN_ALWAYS,
        0,
        0);

    if (!::ReplaceFile(L"World.txt", L"Hello.txt", NULL, REPLACEFILE_IGNORE_MERGE_ERRORS, 0, 0))
    {
        const DWORD err(::GetLastError());
        std::cout << "Uh oh! " << err << "\n";
    }

    ::CloseHandle(fileHandle);
}
```

> Uh oh! 32

32 is `ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION`. If I removed the `::CreateFile` call, the replacement succeeds.

Is there a way to keep an open handle on a replacement file? If not, is there an alternative to `::ReplaceFile` that still has the atomic property described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/deprecation-of-txf)?

Comment: What's the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: `so that no other process is reading the file while the replacement takes place`; If your process can't have an open handle to this file while calling `ReplaceFile`, why do you think another process can and read the file at this time?